# Rails share custom database connection between classes - without class inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have a replica database slave running, where I want to send some readonly calls to, to offload the master. For this reason I would like to create two customs models, that connect separately to that database, so that I can use those, whenever I have the need to offload some queries.

I have two classes:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Rails has the possibility to share custom database connections on model level like this:

```
class MyCustomDbConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection({database: 'www.slavedb.com', port: 5432, pass: 'some'})
end

class ReadonlyCar < MyCustomDbConnection
end

class ReadonlyPrice < MyCustomDbConnection
end
```

While this works well, my use case is that I would ALSO like to have the ´ReadonlyCar´ and `ReadonlyPrice` inherit from the original models that uses the default `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. This is needed to have the `ReadonlyCar` behave exactly like the original one `Car` (business logic). Now I can't do class inheritance from both `ReadonlyCar < MyCustomDbConnection` and `ReadonlyCar < Car`at the same time, so how do I get the full functionality from `Car`, but share the same connection to the slave between both `ReadonlyCar` and `ReadonlyPrice`?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a module where in the included hook you do that call to establish the connection.

```
module MyCustomDbConnection
  def self.included(base)
    base.establish_connection(
      database: 'www.slavedb.com',
      port: 5432,
      pass: 'some'
    )
  end
end

class ReadOnlyCar < Car
  include MyCustomDbConnection
end
```

Comment: Great, any idea how I can confirm, that if I do `ReadonlyCar.first?` and `ReadonlyPrice.first`, that it's actually using the same connection, and not just creating a new connection?

Comment: The included hook is executed everytime the module is included someplace. In your case that means `establish_connection` is called once with `base` being `ReadonlyPrice` and once with `base` being `ReadonlyCar`. Did you want to have exactly one connection? If so you need to use a Singleton. I can expand my answer with that if this is what you actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, The idea is, that I don't want it to with connections if i do e.g. `ReadonlyCar.first.prices.first.car`

Comment: Alos, I would like to be able to access that connection to set the `search_path` (postgresql feature) atomically.

Comment: I don't understand, you don't want it to ....? Also I'm not entirely sure how AR's `establish_connection` works under the hood, so calling it just once may not result in exactly one connection. Also, you do realise that if there's just one connection it would be come a choking point, right?